# Undefined reference to functions in xlib.h while compiling Qt-Everywhere 4.6.3

Tags: qt, compilation, linker, g++

I am compiling Qt-Everywhere 4.6.3 on Ubuntu 12.04.1 32bit for use on mini2440. I was able to compile `qmake` for mini2440 but failed to compile for my laptop for testing. `./configure` gave me no errors (I had to install `libx11-dev` & `libXext-dev` to do so). But on running `make`, I got many linker errors like :

```
.obj/release-shared/qpaintengine_x11.o: In function `QX11PaintEngine::drawPixmap(QRectF const&, QPixmap const&, QRectF const&)':
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x25fb): undefined reference to `XCopyArea'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x264c): undefined reference to `XSetClipOrigin'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2691): undefined reference to `XSetClipMask'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2723): undefined reference to `XCopyArea'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2871): undefined reference to `XSetClipRectangles'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x28bf): undefined reference to `XCreatePixmap'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x28e2): undefined reference to `XCreateGC'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x28fd): undefined reference to `XSetForeground'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2934): undefined reference to `XFillRectangle'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2989): undefined reference to `XSetClipRectangles'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x29dc): undefined reference to `XCopyArea'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x29ef): undefined reference to `XFreeGC'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2a0c): undefined reference to `XSetClipMask'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2a31): undefined reference to `XSetClipOrigin'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2a44): undefined reference to `XFreePixmap'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2ab4): undefined reference to `XSetForeground'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2b16): undefined reference to `XCreateGC'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2b31): undefined reference to `XSetForeground'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2b70): undefined reference to `XFillRectangle'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2b8b): undefined reference to `XSetBackground'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2ba6): undefined reference to `XSetForeground'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2be8): undefined reference to `XSetFillStyle'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2c0f): undefined reference to `XSetTSOrigin'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2c30): undefined reference to `XSetStipple'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2c6f): undefined reference to `XFillRectangle'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2c82): undefined reference to `XFreeGC'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2ca7): undefined reference to `XSetClipOrigin'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2ccc): undefined reference to `XSetClipMask'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2d26): undefined reference to `XCreateGC'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2d51): undefined reference to `XSetBackground'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2d6c): undefined reference to `XSetForeground'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2da3): undefined reference to `XFillRectangle'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2db6): undefined reference to `XFreeGC'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2ddd): undefined reference to `XSetClipMask'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2e0a): undefined reference to `XSetClipOrigin'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2e81): undefined reference to `XSetForeground'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2ebc): undefined reference to `XFillRectangle'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2f07): undefined reference to `XSetClipRectangles'
qpaintengine_x11.cpp:(.text+0x2fa3): undefined reference to `XCopyArea'
```

I do not know what is going wrong. My configure options are :

> ved@ubuntu:~/qt-src/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-4.6.3$ ./configure -prefix /qt-test -release -shared -fast -pch -no-qt3support -qt-sql-sqlite -no-libtiff -no-libmng -qt-libjpeg -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-freetype -no-openssl -nomake examples -nomake demos -nomake tools -optimized-qmake -no-phonon -no-nis -no-opengl -no-cups -no-xcursor -no-xfixes -no-xrandr -no-xrender -no-xkb -no-sm -no-xinerama -no-xshape -no-separate-debug-info -depths 16 -no-qvfb -qt-gfx-linuxfb -no-gfx-qvfb -no-kbd-qvfb -no-mouse-qvfb-qt-kbd-usb -confirm-license -verbose

I have copied the same options as the mini2440 version (except `-xplatform qws/linux-arm-g++` & `-embedded arm`).

Comment: which OS is on your laptop? a Desktop linux distribution??

Comment: @UmNyobe I use Ubuntu 12.04 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a desktop linux distribution follow the directions on [x11 requirements page](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/requirements-x11.html). Besides libx11-dev & libXext-dev you need :

- libfontconfig1-dev
- libfreetype6-dev
- libxcursor-dev
- libxfixes-dev
- libxft-dev
- libxi-dev
- libxrandr-dev
- libxrender-dev

Comment: I have included `-no-xcursor -no-xfixes -no-xrandr -no-xrender -no-xkb -no-sm -no-xinerama -no-xshape` in the config options. Do I need to remove them and add their support?